# MongoDB: dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }

Tags: replication, backup, mongodb, restore

When I'm using mongodump or mongorestore on a replica set these messages appear in the verbose output:

```
dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
```

The replica set is configured for authentication and the user account I'm connecting with has the clusterAdmin role set, which makes me wonder why the clients (mongodump/restore) aren't authorized to execute replSetGetStatus.

The connecting user has the *userAdminAnyDatabase*, *readWriteAnyDatabase*, *dbAdminAnyDatabase* and *clusterAdmin* roles on the admin database.

Here is an exemplified mongodump command:

```
mongodump --host rs0/host0.example.org,host1.example.org,host2.example.org \
          --port 27017 \
          --ssl \
          --ipv6 \
          --verbose \
          --authenticationDatabase admin \
          --username *user* \
          --password *password* \
          --out bakdir \
          --db admin
```

mongod, mongodump and mongorestore are version 2.4.10, installed from the Debian Jessie (stable) repository.

I'd like to know why it fails, what the implications of these failings are and what I possibly can do about it (except switching off authentication ;-). Besides this quirk mongodump/restore seem to do their jobs just fine.

Here is the verbose log output from mongodump (timestamps truncated and hostnames replaced):

```
[Timestamp.381] starting new replica set monitor for replica set rs0 with seed of host0.example.org:27017,host1.example.org:27017,host2.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.381] creating new connection to:host0.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.383] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.412] connected connection!
[Timestamp.412] successfully connected to seed host0.example.org:27017 for replica set rs0
[Timestamp.413] ReplicaSetMonitor::_checkConnection: host0.example.org:27017 { setName: "rs0", ismaster: true, secondary: false, hosts: [ "host0.example.org:27017", "host2.example.org:27017", "host1.example.org:27017" ], primary: "host0.example.org:27017", me: "host0.example.org:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, localTime: new Date(1437578036410), ok: 1.0 }
[Timestamp.413] changing hosts to { 0: "host0.example.org:27017", 1: "host2.example.org:27017", 2: "host1.example.org:27017" } from rs0/
[Timestamp.413] trying to add new host host0.example.org:27017 to replica set rs0
[Timestamp.413] creating new connection to:host0.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.415] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.439] connected connection!
[Timestamp.439] successfully connected to new host host0.example.org:27017 in replica set rs0
[Timestamp.439] trying to add new host host1.example.org:27017 to replica set rs0
[Timestamp.439] creating new connection to:host1.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.440] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.448] connected connection!
[Timestamp.448] successfully connected to new host host1.example.org:27017 in replica set rs0
[Timestamp.448] trying to add new host host2.example.org:27017 to replica set rs0
[Timestamp.448] creating new connection to:host2.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.448] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.477] connected connection!
[Timestamp.477] successfully connected to new host host2.example.org:27017 in replica set rs0
[Timestamp.477] creating new connection to:host0.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.478] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.500] connected connection!
[Timestamp.501] dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
[Timestamp.501] _check : rs0/host0.example.org:27017,host1.example.org:27017,host2.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.501] ReplicaSetMonitor::_checkConnection: host0.example.org:27017 { setName: "rs0", ismaster: true, secondary: false, hosts: [ "host0.example.org:27017", "host2.example.org:27017", "host1.example.org:27017" ], primary: "host0.example.org:27017", me: "host0.example.org:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, localTime: new Date(1437578036498), ok: 1.0 }
[Timestamp.502] dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
[Timestamp.502] Primary for replica set rs0 changed to host0.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.503] ReplicaSetMonitor::_checkConnection: host0.example.org:27017 { setName: "rs0", ismaster: true, secondary: false, hosts: [ "host0.example.org:27017", "host2.example.org:27017", "host1.example.org:27017" ], primary: "host0.example.org:27017", me: "host0.example.org:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, localTime: new Date(1437578036500), ok: 1.0 }
[Timestamp.503] dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
[Timestamp.504] ReplicaSetMonitor::_checkConnection: host1.example.org:27017 { setName: "rs0", ismaster: false, secondary: true, hosts: [ "host1.example.org:27017", "host2.example.org:27017", "host0.example.org:27017" ], primary: "host0.example.org:27017", me: "host1.example.org:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, localTime: new Date(1437578036504), ok: 1.0 }
[Timestamp.505] creating new connection to:host1.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.506] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.514] connected connection!
[Timestamp.515] dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
[Timestamp.516] ReplicaSetMonitor::_checkConnection: host2.example.org:27017 { setName: "rs0", ismaster: false, secondary: true, hosts: [ "host2.example.org:27017", "host1.example.org:27017", "host0.example.org:27017" ], primary: "host0.example.org:27017", me: "host2.example.org:27017", maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216, maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000, localTime: new Date(1437578036516), ok: 1.0 }
[Timestamp.516] creating new connection to:host2.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.516] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.544] connected connection!
[Timestamp.544] dbclient_rs replSetGetStatus failed{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: "unauthorized" }
[Timestamp.544] replica set monitor for replica set rs0 started, address is rs0/host0.example.org:27017,host1.example.org:27017,host2.example.org:27017
connected to: rs0/host0.example.org,host1.example.org,host2.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.545] creating new connection to:host0.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.545] BackgroundJob starting: ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher
[Timestamp.545] [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
[Timestamp.546] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.571] connected connection!
[Timestamp.573] creating new connection to:host1.example.org:27017
[Timestamp.574] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
[Timestamp.582] connected connection!
[Timestamp.585] DATABASE: admin  to     ./admin
[Timestamp.589]     admin.system.indexes to ./admin/system.indexes.bson
[Timestamp.591]          2 objects
[Timestamp.591]     skipping collection: admin.system.users.$user_1_userSource_1
[Timestamp.591]     skipping collection: admin.system.users.$_id_
[Timestamp.591]     admin.system.users to ./admin/system.users.bson
[Timestamp.593]          2 objects
[Timestamp.593]     Metadata for admin.system.users to ./admin/system.users.metadata.json
[Timestamp.593]     admin.system.profile to ./admin/system.profile.bson
[Timestamp.646]          2612 objects
[Timestamp.646]     Metadata for admin.system.profile to ./admin/system.profile.metadata.json
```

And here are the corresponding mongodb.log files for the replica set servers. Host addresses and user credentials replaced. Timestamps truncated except milliseconds. Mongodump was executed on host2. Backup was taken from host1. The `SocketException`s in the server logs might be noteworthy.

host0.example.org (primary):

```
[Timestamp.381] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40668 #46757 (8 connections now open)
[Timestamp.410] [conn46757] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.410] [conn46757] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.410] [conn46757] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:341 0ms
[Timestamp.413] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40669 #46758 (9 connections now open)
[Timestamp.416] [journal] journal WRITETODATAFILES 0.144ms
[Timestamp.476] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40672 #46759 (10 connections now open)
[Timestamp.497] [conn46759] runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.497] [conn46759] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.497] [conn46759] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.497] [conn46759] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:62 0ms
[Timestamp.498] [conn46757] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40668 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40668] 
[Timestamp.498] [conn46757] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40668 (9 connections now open)
[Timestamp.498] [conn46758] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.498] [conn46758] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.498] [conn46758] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:341 0ms
[Timestamp.499] [conn46759] runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.499] [conn46759] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.499] [conn46759] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.499] [conn46759] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:62 0ms
[Timestamp.500] [conn46758] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.500] [conn46758] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.500] [conn46758] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:341 0ms
[Timestamp.500] [conn46759] runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.500] [conn46759] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.500] [conn46759] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.501] [conn46759] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:62 0ms
[Timestamp.544] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56132 #46760 (10 connections now open)
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760] runQuery called admin.$cmd { getnonce: 1 }
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760] run command admin.$cmd { getnonce: 1 }
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760] command admin.$cmd command: { getnonce: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:65 0ms
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760] runQuery called admin.$cmd { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760] run command admin.$cmd { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.569] [conn46760]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.570] [conn46760] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:235 reslen:79 0ms
[Timestamp.623] [journal] journal WRITETODATAFILES 0.073ms
[Timestamp.648] [conn46758] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40669 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40669] 
[Timestamp.648] [conn46758] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40669 (9 connections now open)
[Timestamp.649] [conn46759] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40672 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40672] 
[Timestamp.649] [conn46759] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:40672 (8 connections now open)
[Timestamp.649] [conn46760] user:**user**@admin SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56132 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56132] 
[Timestamp.649] [conn46760] user:**user**@admin end connection <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56132 (7 connections now open)
[Timestamp.677] [conn46756] user:**user**@admin SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56124 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56124] 
[Timestamp.677] [conn46756] user:**user**@admin end connection <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:56124 (6 connections now open)
```

host1.example.org (secondary & host from which the backup was taken):

```
[Timestamp.442] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33206 #46856 (3 connections now open)
[Timestamp.504] [conn46856] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.504] [conn46856] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.504] [conn46856] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:341 0ms
[Timestamp.507] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33209 #46857 (4 connections now open)
[Timestamp.515] [conn46857] runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.515] [conn46857] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.515] [conn46857] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.515] [conn46857] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:62 0ms
[Timestamp.575] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:60931 #46858 (5 connections now open)
[Timestamp.582] [conn46858] runQuery called admin.$cmd { getnonce: 1 }
[Timestamp.582] [conn46858] run command admin.$cmd { getnonce: 1 }
[Timestamp.582] [conn46858] command admin.$cmd command: { getnonce: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:65 0ms
[Timestamp.583] [conn46858] runQuery called admin.$cmd { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.583] [conn46858] run command admin.$cmd { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.583] [conn46858]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" }
[Timestamp.584] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { authenticate: 1, nonce: "**nonce**", user: "**user**", key: "**key**" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:393 reslen:79 0ms
[Timestamp.585] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.$cmd { isdbgrid: 1 }
[Timestamp.585] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin run command admin.$cmd { isdbgrid: 1 }
[Timestamp.585] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { isdbgrid: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:99 0ms
[Timestamp.586] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.system.indexes {}
[Timestamp.586] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin query admin.system.indexes ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:49 nreturned:2 reslen:207 0ms
[Timestamp.587] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.system.namespaces {}
[Timestamp.587] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin query admin.system.namespaces ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:5 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:39 nreturned:5 reslen:254 0ms
[Timestamp.589] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.$cmd { count: "system.indexes", query: {} }
[Timestamp.589] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin run command admin.$cmd { count: "system.indexes", query: {} }
[Timestamp.589] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { count: "system.indexes", query: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:17 reslen:48 0ms
[Timestamp.590] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.$cmd { availablequeryoptions: 1 }
[Timestamp.590] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin run command admin.$cmd { availablequeryoptions: 1 }
[Timestamp.590] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { availablequeryoptions: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:50 0ms
[Timestamp.591] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.system.indexes { query: {}, $snapshot: true }
[Timestamp.591] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin query admin.system.indexes query: { query: {}, $snapshot: true } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:25 nreturned:2 reslen:207 0ms
[Timestamp.592] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.$cmd { count: "system.users", query: {} }
[Timestamp.592] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin run command admin.$cmd { count: "system.users", query: {} }
[Timestamp.592] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { count: "system.users", query: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:13 reslen:48 0ms
[Timestamp.593] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.system.users { query: {}, $snapshot: true }
[Timestamp.593] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin query admin.system.users query: { query: {}, $snapshot: true } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:2 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:79 nreturned:2 reslen:350 0ms
[Timestamp.594] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.$cmd { count: "system.profile", query: {} }
[Timestamp.594] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin run command admin.$cmd { count: "system.profile", query: {} }
[Timestamp.594] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin command admin.$cmd command: { count: "system.profile", query: {} } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:14 reslen:48 0ms
[Timestamp.595] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin runQuery called admin.system.profile { query: {}, $snapshot: true }
[Timestamp.595] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin query admin.system.profile query: { query: {}, $snapshot: true } cursorid:**cursorid** ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 exhaust:1 nscanned:102 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:163 nreturned:101 reslen:38501 0ms
[Timestamp.597] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin getmore admin.system.profile query: { query: {}, $snapshot: true } cursorid:**cursorid** ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:1739 nreturned:2511 reslen:960456 1ms
[Timestamp.651] [conn46857] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33209 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33209] 
[Timestamp.651] [conn46857] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33209 (4 connections now open)
[Timestamp.651] [conn46856] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33206 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33206] 
[Timestamp.651] [conn46856] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:33206 (3 connections now open)
[Timestamp.652] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:60931 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv6.addr>:60931] 
[Timestamp.652] [conn46858] user:**user**@admin end connection <backup.client.ipv6.addr>:60931 (2 connections now open)
```

host2.example.org (secondary & backup-client):

```
[Timestamp.449] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58052 #46602 (4 connections now open)
[Timestamp.474] [conn46601] user:__system@local runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", v: 4, pv: 1, checkEmpty: false, from: "host1.example.org:27017" }
[Timestamp.475] [conn46601] user:__system@local run command admin.$cmd { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", v: 4, pv: 1, checkEmpty: false, from: "host1.example.org:27017" }
[Timestamp.475] [conn46601] user:__system@local command: { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", v: 4, pv: 1, checkEmpty: false, from: "host1.example.org:27017" }
[Timestamp.475] [conn46601] user:__system@local command admin.$cmd command: { replSetHeartbeat: "rs0", v: 4, pv: 1, checkEmpty: false, from: "host1.example.org:27017" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:164 0ms
[Timestamp.516] [conn46602] runQuery called admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.516] [conn46602] run command admin.$cmd { ismaster: 1 }
[Timestamp.516] [conn46602] command admin.$cmd command: { ismaster: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:334 0ms
[Timestamp.516] [initandlisten] connection accepted from <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58055 #46603 (5 connections now open)
[Timestamp.544] [conn46603] runQuery called admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.544] [conn46603] run command admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.544] [conn46603] command denied: { replSetGetStatus: 1 }
[Timestamp.544] [conn46603] command admin.$cmd command: { replSetGetStatus: 1 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0  reslen:62 0ms
[Timestamp.650] [conn46602] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58052 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58052] 
[Timestamp.651] [conn46602] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58052 (4 connections now open)
[Timestamp.651] [conn46603] SocketException: remote: <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58055 error: 9001 socket exception [CLOSED] server [<backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58055] 
[Timestamp.651] [conn46603] end connection <backup.client.ipv4.addr>:58055 (3 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Answer (leaving for people that might hit this because of the simple explanation):

The `clusterAdmin` role only applies when you authenticate against the `admin` database, so unless you specify the [`--authenticationDatabase` option](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--authenticationDatabase) to be `admin` when you are running `mongodump/mongorestore` I suspect you are getting a lesser privilege when authing against the DB you are dumping/restoring and hence seeing the errors.

Follow up:

This issue looks like a bug, but besides some tangential issues, I can't find an issue that corresponds to a fix here.  As of writing this, there have been 2 major releases since 2.4.10 (released April 2014), and even 2.4 has several subsequent updates (2.4.15 was release April 2015). Normally I would recommend filing a bug but 2.4 has [reached EOL](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy), so unless you can reproduce this with 2.6 or 3.0 then it won't be actioned.

Additionally, the tools (dump, restore etc.) have since been completely refactored (even have their [own repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools) and [project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS/)) and are even written in a different language now.

I don't believe the errors are impacting your data dump, so it's up to you in terms of how much effort you want to expend on this, but at a minimum I would recommend upgrading to a non-EOL version of MongoDB and retrying your process.

Comment: Nope :-( I connect with `--authenticateDatabase admin` and get the authentication failure even when I backup the admin database. I'll update the question by adding the roles of the connecting user and an examplified mongodump command.

Comment: has this ever been a 2.6+ replica set?

Comment: Also, can you paste the full log line? I am interested to see if this is from the mongodump/restore connection or from something else - the replica set monitor is where I have usually seen that messaging, but that is independent of the dump/restore tools

Comment: The replica set has always been 2.4.10 (Debian Jessie). I appended the complete log to the question.

Comment: It's hard to be sure, because I can't see the thread ID or the corresponding timestamp for mongodump, but it looks to me like those errors are independent of the dump, do you have a keyFile configured correctly for those hosts to talk to each other?  The monitor will use the keyFile to auth itself to the other hosts in the set, if it is not identical on all hosts you would get errors like that

Comment: I just appended the server logs, they include the thread ID. The key files are the same; replication, failover and recovery works like a charm.

Comment: I amended my answer - if I still worked at MongoDB I might poke a dev to see what's up, but I think the answer would end up being the same.  The only "odd" thing I see in your set up is the use of IPV6 which is not widely used (and certainly was not when 2.4 was current), so that might be a possible cause, but I am just speculating at this point

Comment: To conclude this, I reconfigured the servers to use IPv4 only but the behavior persists. Too bad that the packages from the MongoDB repository only support Debian up to version Wheezy (oldstable) at the moment. Anyways thanks for your expertise!

Comment: I'll bet the main issue with Jesse support is the switch to systemd - the binaries will work fine, but you may need to sort out your own service